# What's the most efficient algorithm for partitioning a binary tree into K subtrees with minimal maximum height?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, dynamic-programming

#### Partitioning the binary tree into subtrees with minimal-maximum height

I'm working with an algorithm that can solve binary tree partition problems.

I will partite the binary tree into K subtrees with minimizing (maximum height among K subtrees).

For example, when partitioning the tree with N vertices into N subtrees, the algorithm would return 0, because the tree will be divided into every single node.

More precisely, the distance **D** for every node **V** is defined by a recurrence relation.

```
D(V) = 0                    ... If V is a root of subtree
     = Infinity             ... If V is a root of original tree and V is not a root of subtree
     = 1 + D(parent node of V)    ... Otherwise
```

I thought this problem can be solved with the greedy method but found the countercase: linear graph

Which algorithm is efficient in this case, and is it able to solve with dynamic programming?

Comment: I don't see how linear graph is a countercase...

Comment: Seeing a good example would be very helpful for understanding the task.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest an algorithm with a complexity of O(n log(n)).

Firstly, the minimal maximum height of K subtrees is at most `ceil(N/K)-1`.

Then you do binary search for h in the interval `[0, ceil(N/K)-1]` to find the number of trees that have the height at most h.

The idea is to select subtrees from the leaves to the root.

For the given height `h` do the following:

Set `n_subtrees = 0`

Start with `q` equal to the list of leaf nodes.

While `q` is not empty:

- For each node `v` in `q`:

  - For `i` from `0` to `h` inclusive

    - Remember in node `v` the maximum number `i_max` of `i` among all children and the number of children remaining
    - If this is not the last child, break the loop
    - If this is the last child set `i = i_max[v]`
    - Set `height[v] = i`
    - If `v` is root, set `n_subtrees += 1` and break the loop
    - Set `v = parent(v)`
    - If `i == h`, add `v` to the list `q_new` and set `n_subtrees += 1`
- Set `q = q_new`

If you get `n_subtrees > K`, set `left = h`, otherwise set `right = h` and continue the binary search.

Finally you need to reconstruct the partition. Starting from the root node select a subtree of height `height[v]` and add all the children of the leaf nodes to a queue. Continue doing the same with the nodes in the queue.

UPD: Instead of `for i from 0 to h inclusive` you should do a while loop, because the value of `i` can change inside the loop.